# Yammer for authentication just like facebook

Tags: yammer

We are creating a web application that can only be accessed by People who have Yammer account. We have done this before for Facebook, Google etc, but not for #Yammer. I tired this by creating external network but that was to not useful. Please let me know if that is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need a Yammer network and to create an app in it, so you can use the API. Follow these [steps](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/getting-started). You'll then need to use the OAuth2 protocol that is set by Yammer for the authentication piece. This means anyone with a Yammer login AND their home networks have run 3rd party apps enabled will be able to login. If their home networks do not have 3rd party apps enabled, those users will not be able to login.

For simplicity, I recommend to use the Sign In with Yammer button code https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/authentication but you can also create your experience using the server side or client side flow, [documented here](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/oauth-2) and the SDKs.

Note to have anybody from any network be able to use your app, once you are finished coding it, you'll need to apply to have it globalized by Yammer (and potentially also list it in the app directory).